# Angular Material List design

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I need to design a parent container, which has fixed length child list items (150 px).

1) when the parent container is resized the children list Items should flow from left to right and should break into New Row & the space between the child list items should be evenly distributed.

pls tell me how to achieve this using angular material. pls see the below picture for my requirement.

[image: This is what i want]

I tried to implement this.. using the following code.

```
<div layout-padding layout-fill layout="row" layout-wrap layout-align="space-around start">

    <div ng-repeat="student in students"
         style="width: 150px; height: 52px;line-height: 52px;min-height: 52px;max-height: 52px;
            margin:8px;padding: 0px; border: solid 1px"
         draggable="true">

        {{student.name}}

    </div>

</div>
```

but this is what I've got
[image]

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation for layout? You should be able to just do: `layout="row"` on the parent container. Since you have fixed widths already you don't need to do anything to the children. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction

Comment: I've done something with Material as well. I think the Material Design way of doing layout is using flex directives/classes instead of a fixed width. I think you'll have to write custom css to do what you want.

Comment: @mike Harison, sir already I've included layout="row" in my parent container. see my result image and my implementation code.!

Comment: @raichu when I use layout="space-around start" in the parent container everything works as per my need but, the last row items are my problem.. what shall I do to align them to the left.!

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. In that case, the reason space is being wasted is because you HAVE fixed widths for the children. You can use the flex directive which is also included in the documentation I linked to. If you want 4 per row use `flex="25"`, 5 per row `flex="50"` etc.

Comment: @MikeHarrison ahhh.. brillliant sir.. thank u.. u've opened my eyes..!

Comment: For some reason can't edit my comment but just realized `flex="50"` would be 2 per row; `flex="20"` would be 5 per row. Oops!

Comment: @MikeHarrison sir.. see my answer below.. I followed ur instruction and the results are awesome.. thank u..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mr. @MikeHarrison... I've edited my code like below & the result is exactly what I've wanted.!

```
<div class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-fill layout-wrap layout-align="start start">

    <md-list-item ng-repeat="student in students" draggable="true" flex-xs="100" flex-sm="50" flex-md="33"
                  flex-gt-md="25" class="md-3-line" ng-click="alert('hi')">

        <img src="../../_resources/images/boy_real.jpg" class="md-avatar"/>

        <div class="md-list-item-text">
            <h3> {{student.name}} </h3>
            <h4> {{student.roll}} </h4>
            <p> {{student.desc + ' guy'}} </p>
        </div>

        <md-divider md-inset></md-divider>

    </md-list-item>

</div>
```

and the result in a browser is

[image]

and the result in a mobile is

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Yea the flex capabilities of angular material are a lifesaver for situations like this. Makes your HTML very clean and easy to read as well.

Answer (score 1):

That will be a totally new control, you will need to create your own using "pieces" of angular material.  For example, you can create the list items out of the angular material md-button, host all the buttons inside a md-content if you want scrolling and use the md-layout to align your items.  Obviously the most important part will be the styles for your control to have the look and feel of angular material.

The point here is that you will need to create your custom control.  I recommend creating your own control module and add the necessary directives, services for you control to work.

Comment: Yep I did that for creating an accordion which angular material did not have at the time  I needed it. If you create a custom control you can even share it with the open source community.